# How to find the top n keys based on the value in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a pyspark dataframe whose schema look like this :

```
root
 |-- query: string (nullable = true)
 |-- collect_list(docId): array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- prod_count_dict: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = true)
```

and the dataframe look like this :

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|               query| collect_list(docId)|     prod_count_dict|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|1/2 inch plywood ...|[471097-153-12CC,...|[530320-62634-100...|
|             1416445|[1416445-83-HHM5S...|[1054482-2251-FFC...
```

Note that the column `prod_count_dict` is a dictionary with key values pairs like:

```
{x: 12, a: 16, b:1, f:3, ....}
```

What I want to do is I want to only pick the `keys` of the `top n` largest `values` from the key: value pair and store it in another column as a list like : [x, a,..] corresponding to that row.

I tried this below code, but It is giving me an error, Is there a way I can solve this particular problem?

```
@F.udf(StringType())
def create_label(x):
# If the length of dictionary is less then 20, I want to return the keys of all the items in the dict.
    if len(x) >= 20:  
        val_sort = sorted(list(x.values()), reverse = True)
        cutoff = {k: v for (k, v) in x.items() if v > val_sort[20]}
        return cutoff.keys()
    else:
        return x.keys()

label_df = label_count_df.withColumn("label", create_label("prod_count_dict"))
label_df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UDF that you have written is correct. You only need to change the code where you actually use it. This can easily be done if you use `.map` in `rdd`:

```
#Let the udf that you have written be a normal python function
def create_label(x):
# If the length of the dictionary is less than 20, I want to return the keys of all the items in the dict.
    if len(x) >= 20:  
        val_sort = sorted(list(x.values()), reverse = True)
        cutoff = {k: v for (k, v) in x.items() if v > val_sort[20]}
        return cutoff.keys()
    else:
        return x.keys()
```

The part that you need to change is:

```
label_df_col = ['query','prod_count_dict']
label_df = label_count_df.rdd.map(lambda x:(x.query, create_label(x.prod_count_dict))).toDF(label_df_col)
label_df.show()
```

This should work.

Comment: This works, I thought I would be able to do it with df.withColumn

Answer (score 0):

First I would explode the dict:

```
df = df.select("*", f.explode("prod_count_dict").alias("key", "value"))
```

After that, you can use the Window function to get the top n values per key

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy(df['key']).orderBy(df['value'].desc())

df.select('*', f.rank().over(w).alias('rank'))\
  .filter(col('rank') <= 2) \  # setup N here
  .drop('rank')
```